# change username and password for phpmyadmin in aws ec2

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am new to AWS. Recently i created a instance over aws and i deployed my react and nodejs code over it. now the database i have used is mysql/phpmyadmin. so i have uploaded phpmyadmin folder in var/www/html folder and access the url, i am getting the login page for phpmyadmin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTCaW.png)

Now the problem is i don't know what is the username and password for phpmyadmin. Maybe the username is root but i don't know its password. Can anybody help is solving this issue.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community what code do you expect? this is not a coding issue. do read the post before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

what version are you using? Try root as Username, "" as Password.

On my server,there are some more entries.Like "Server".

Version information: 5.1.1

Server: Your mysql host and port. eg:127.0.0.1:3306

Username: Your mysql username. eg:root

Password: Your mysql user password. eg:xxx

[image]

Check file config.inc.php in phpmyadmin root path.Have you ever modified the configuration here?
Maybe the option "Server" has default value, localhost:3306 .Username and Password is your mysql user&password.